# Use Workflow to update checkbox between objects

Tags: workflow, field-update

I need to update a checkbox field on the `Lead` object called `Grant Access` by replicating the same type field `Grant Access` on the `Campaign Object`. I cannot use a Formula field due to limitations surrounding `Lead /Campaign`. (A lead can only be attached to campaign from the first time it is created). I need to use Workflow to resolve this but I am having trouble doing so. Ie. When the `Campaign` field `Grant Access` is checked, every lead that is created and related to that campaign should have field `Grant Access` checked. And Vice Versa. Is this possible?

Comment: You can attach a lead to a campaign at any time; the "campaign" field is a convenience field for adding a lead to a campaign on creation (e.g. web to lead). To add the lead after creation, you can use the campaign's manage members button, by running a lead report and using that report's add to campaign button, or by adding the campaign history related list to the lead page layout, and adding the campaign from there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No this is not possible. In general (there are some exceptions) you can only update fields on the same record that triggered the workflow. You can also only update one record - not all the related/child object.

This is also complicated by being a many to many relation.  A lead can be in many campaigns and a campaign can contain many leads.

To solve your requirements you would need to look into writing triggers.

Comment: This would be a pretty easy trigger to develop also.. Very doable